# Convert Int to Char Array

Tags: c++, char, int

I need to make a class called MyInt which handles any size positive numbers by creating an int array. I am making a constructor to be used in converting an int (any size supported by ints) into a MyInt. I need to convert the int into a char array and then read digit by digit into the int array. So my question is, without using any libraries except `<iostream>` `<iomanip>` and `<cstring>` how can I convert an int with multiple digits into a character array?

Comment: Why do you need to convert to a `char` array?  Why not just go directly to the final `int` array?

Comment: How can I do that? Convert an int into an int array?

Comment: What does the content of the int array need to be?

Comment: Any larger number. Like 987657656344632652457985675637659045635732876499873409427034965563240987 or something.

Comment: So what would be the value of `intarray[0]`, `intarray[1]`, etc.?  And where is that large value coming from?  It can't be coming from an `int`.

Comment: The large value is a MyInt already, it's so I can add a MyInt to a regular int (the int gets converted automatically). I figured it out though

Comment: Do you mean you want to change int to your MyInt, but your MyInt accept a char sequence? So, you need to change the int to a char array, and then used to construct MyInt? If so, I think maybe the "sprintf" could help you.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to make a `char` array as an intermediary step. The digits (I assume in base 10) can be obtained one by one using modulo 10 operations. Something like:

```
convert(int *ar, const int i)
{
    int p, tmp;

    tmp = i
    while (tmp != 0)
    {
        ar[p] = tmp % 10;
        tmp   = (tmp - ar[p])/10;
        p++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want, but:

```
int myInt = 30;
char *chars = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&myInt);
```

And you can get the 4 separate char's:

```
chars[0]; // is the first char
chars[1]; // is the second char
chars[2]; // is the third char, and
chars[3]; // is the fourth/last char
```

...but I'm not entirely sure if that's what you are looking for.

Comment: This does not work, at least not if I understand the question. Your code produces a character array with one character: the character with the ASCII value of 30. It will not produce a character array with the '3' character, the '0' character, and a null terminator, which is (if I understand correctly) what the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way of doing that conversion with such restraints is as follows:

```
function convert:
    //find out length of integer (integer division works well)
    //make a char array of a big enough size (including the \0 if you need to print it)
    //use division and modulus to fill in the array one character at a time
    //if you want readable characters, don't forget to adjust for them
    //don't forget to set the null character if you need it
```

I hope I didn't misunderstand your question, but that worked for me, giving me a printable array that read the same as the integer itself.